# App Engine Bulkloader How do I disable "Backing off due to errors"

Tags: google-app-engine

I have to upload a large number of entities (800k) with the App Engine bulkloader. Everything is set up and things are going well, except I get a mysterious error that causes this to happen:

```
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 2.0 seconds
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 4.0 seconds
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 8.0 seconds
```

This is fine, until I let it run all day:

```
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 2048.0 seconds
[WorkerThread-0] Backing off due to errors: 4096.0 seconds
```

How can I disable this? It's making my uploads take forever. Quite literally, this happens every thousand entities, so I could be waiting for `2^sum(1 to 800)` seconds. This is clearly not ideal.

I have no idea what the error is other than it says I have "errors", but things seem to be uploading just fine if I stop and resume it every hour.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to split your task into smaller chunks say 50-100 entities, and each chunk to use a new loader to upload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified `google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py` to ignore the `self.__backing_off` variable. Specifically, I reset it to `1.0` on line 426.

What a ridiculous design by Google...

Comment: In SDK v1.7.0 `self.__backing_off` does not exist. I changed `BACKOFF_FACTOR` in the same file from `2.0` to `1.0` and this gave the desired result.

Comment: Yea, I asked this question about a week before 1.7 was released.